# Express: req.body is a string, converting it to an object

Tags: json, string, express

I have a React form and an Express backend sending an email via SMTP with Nodemailer. The form is being submitted on the front end just fine, and the backend is successfully sending the email. However, the values from the form are undefined in the email.

On the client side I am sending a POST request that looks like this:

```
const postData = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            mode: "no-cors",
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                name: values.name,
                company: values.company,
                phone: values.phone,
                email: values.email,
                heardAboutUs: values.heardAboutUs,
                region: values.region,
                message: values.howWeCanHelp
            }),
        };
```

My Express route for this POST looks like this:

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const output = `
        <h2>New Request a Demo Contact</h2>
        <ul>
             // All these values are undefined
            <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
            <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
            <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
            <li>Heard About Us: ${req.body.heardAboutUs}</li>
            <li>Region: ${req.body.region}</li>
            <li>How We Can Help: ${req.body.message}</li>
        </ul>
    `;

    // SMTP/Nodemailer code below that handles the email
}
```

When I console.log req.body the data is a string of JSON that looks like this:

```
Preview URL: false
[Object: null prototype] {
  '{"name":"Nick","company":"My Company Name","phone":"8005555555","email":"","heardAboutUs":"Recommended by a friend or colleague","region":"North America","message":"hello this is my message"}': ''
}
```

How can I convert this JSON string into an object so that the values inside of `output` are not undefined?

I have tried `JSON.parse(req.body)` but that doesn't work. I get a `Cannot convert object to primitive value` error.

Comment: Why do you stringify the body ? Maybe the lib you're using doesn't need the stringify. Have you try without stringify the body ?

Comment: When I remove the stringify the result I get when logging req.body is: `[Object: null prototype] { '[object Object]': '' }

Comment: Are you using the body parser  as it should be done ?